# Antialising in KML layer in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map created in My Maps, and I wand to embed it in a website, however I'd like to have InfoWindows on marker click instead of the default side panel, and change the description a bit.
From what I found, the only way to do so is to use a regular Google Maps API and add my data onto it with a KML layer. This is working, however, the icons (the pins) are highly pixelated and look terrible. When using the same map via embed (or simply opening it) they are OK.
Would really appreciate any help with the issue. Probably there is another way of adding a custom map to an API-powered map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I've come up with is: no way to achieve what I'm looking for.

When exporting KML layers, Google scales all icons to 32X32 px, and then scales them up (kml file contains scale 1.1 directive). Even if you change the scale, the files remain 32X32, so it does not help; you need to create another files, in other words: the kml exported from Google is not usable if you have custom png icons.

I ended up using regular markers instead of KML layer.